# How to solve a reCaptcha in advance using a web scraper?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, recaptcha

I'm currently in the process of trying to solve a reCaptcha. One of the suggestions received was a method called token farming.

For example, it's possible to farm for reCaptcha tokens from another site, and within 2 minutes, apply one of the farmed tokens to the site I'm trying to solve by changing the site's code on the back.

Unfortunately, wasn't able to get any further explanations as to how to go about doing so, especially changing the site's code on the back.

If anyone’s able to elaborate or give insights on the process, would really appreciate the expertise.

Comment: To clarify, are you presenting captcha challenges to humans and then trying to use the solution in the website that the captcha was set up to protect, on an automated basis?

Comment: Looks like attempt to break into the captcha system

Comment: @halfer I was informed that you can solve a reCaptcha at a site and retrieve a solved token, and within 2 minutes, if I were to go to another site with a reCaptcha, I can use the prior solved reCaptcha token to solve the current reCaptcha.

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin Yes, web scraping to solve reCaptcha.

Comment: I mean what you want doesn't look right and fair. Why would you even need it? I think that's what the majority of users reading this question would like to know.

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin Just for practice with web scraping and to see if it is really a possibility

Comment: SO is a public site, anybody can read all the questions and answers. And all of them are indexed in search engines. Imagine that an answer to your question would cause a hacker to break into reCaptcha and do something very, very nasty. I think the same danger is and will be preventing people with this information from publishing it here or wherever else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142376/discussion-between-andrew-cherevatkin-and-ly-maneug).

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin: I think it's OK to discuss hacking here, since we cannot know if the OP (or subsequent readers) have good or bad purposes in mind. This has been discussed a few times over on the _Meta_ site. However, there is no attempt presented here, so it can probably be closed as "too broad".

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin For the second time around, I mean no harm, so at this point, you can take it however you feel like. Regardless, I will be continuing my learning.

Answer (score 10):

Token farming / token harvesting has been described here in detail: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-16/materials/asia-16-Sivakorn-Im-Not-a-Human-Breaking-the-Google-reCAPTCHA-wp.pdf

The approach for "token farming" discussed in this paper is based on the following mechanism:

1. Each user that visits a site with recaptcha is assigned a `recaptcha-token`.
2. This token is used to identify the user over multiple site visits and to to mark him a legitimate (or illegitimate) user.
3. Depending on various factors like age of the recaptcha-token, user behavior and browser configuration the user on each visit is either presented with one of the various recaptcha versions or even no captcha at all.

(more details can be extracted from their code here: https://github.com/neuroradiology/InsideReCaptcha)

Means, if one can create a huge number of fresh and clean tokens for a target site and age them for 9 days (that's what the article found out), these tokens can be used for accessing recaptcha a few protected sites before ever seeing a recaptcha.

To my understanding, such a fresh token has to be passed as a Cookie to the site in question.

**However I recall having read somewhere that google closed this gap within a few days after this presentation**

Also most probably there are other, similar approaches that have been labeled "token farming".

As far as I know all these approaches exploited loopholes in the recaptcha system and these loopholes were closed by google really fast - often even before the paper or presentation went public as responsible authors usually inform google in advance.

So for you this is most probably only of academic value or for learning about proper protection of captcha systems and token based services in general.

**update**

A quick check on a few recaptcha protected sites showed that the current system now scrambles the cookies, but the recaptcha-token can be found in the recaptcha form as two hidden input elements with partially different values and the id="recaptcha-token".

When visiting such a page with a clean browser you will get a new recaptcha token which you can save away and insert into the same form later when needed. *At least that's the theory, it is very likely that all the cookies and some long term persisted stuff in your browser will keep you from doing this.*

Comment: Appreciate the insight. I actually did go over the doc, but did not go much into details as to how to go about implementing it. It's for a learning purpose and believe there is still a loophole. So would like to give it an attempt, but not sure as to what the suggestion means by changing the site's code on the back. Does it mean the HTML page source? Did give it a try but did not change anything.

Comment: Added details to my answer, the token has to be passed to the site as a cookie. However, you won't be able to reproduce any of the results in this presentation, as google closed this loophole last year.

Comment: Really appreciate the insight! Been interested to learn. For clarification, `recaptcha-token` is being saved as a web token? And what was the process in passing a fresh token as a cookie? Does it mean, a user solves a reCaptcha, and that would store a web token in the storage. Then simply by going to a target, reCaptcha site, that is passing a token as a cookie, since the token will still be in the storage?

Comment: That's the way it used to work, did a quick check on current recaptcha sites and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response again! I did recognize what you have described in fact. By saving away, you are referring to the web storage, correct? And could you elaborate on the insertion to the same form -- this part I never quiet understood? Do you mean manually change the source page with the new reCaptcha token in the web storage?

Comment: Saving away = storing the token somewhere for later use ... in a text file, a database

Comment: The token would then either be inserted either by manipulating the DOM model in the browser before sending the recaptcha request/form - or if emulating the recaptcha request it would be inserted there.

Comment: Got it, and the new reCaptcha token you are referring to, is only obtained once solved, correct? Or just by simply visiting a site with a reCaptcha. Interesting. So once I've obtained the reCaptcha token, and visit the target site with a new reCaptcha, I should simply manipulate the DOM model? And once I have, the reCaptcha would just allow for a bypass?

Comment: The token is created on the first visit. And unless the browser and IP you are using shows any suspicious behavior, you'll have a few free visits on such a fresh token without having to answer any captcha. But it is very likely that harvesting the tokens and injecting them later won't work. I would be really really surprised if it did.

Comment: So to confirm. If I were to visit a site with a reCaptcha as a first visit, without having to solve it, the token is created. Then if I were to visit another site with a reCaptcha, I might not need to answer any reCaptcha? Just interested in this loophole, whether it works or not. If you can describe since the start of harvesting for the tokens and injecting them, would really help clarify, especially this portion: `Obtained the reCaptcha token, visit the target site with a new reCaptcha, simply manipulate the DOM model? And once I have, the reCaptcha would just allow for a bypass?`

Comment: Back when the above mentioned presentation was held it worked like you say. But the authors recommended to bind the recaptcha token to a particular site and also there will have been other improvements since then, so you are describing how it would have been working back then, but it very likely won't work anymore.